# Discriminant Analysis when your data is not normally distributed

Tags: r, linear-discriminant

I want to implement the method Discriminant Analysis but none of the variables of my dataset is normally distributed.So, I can not implement LDA or QDA. I have heard that I can implement Discriminant Analysis based on the likelihood of the observation. Is there a way to implement this in RStudio?

Comment: I have voted to migrate this question to [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/), because it seems to be more a question about statistics than about R code. See, for instance, [this CV post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/110908/linear-discriminant-analysis-and-non-normally-distributed-data) and [this one](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/71489/three-versions-of-discriminant-analysis-differences-and-how-to-use-them).

Comment: Ok, sorry for my mistake